# How to create a responsive menu with angular js?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web design. Which is the most suitable method for creating a webpage which are perfectly viewed in desktop and mobile screens? I am confused what should I learn if know a little basics in angular js. What should I learn for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need AngularJS to make resposive sites! it depends on the css, if you are going with Angular i would recommend you to check out [`AngularMaterial`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/), 
Or you can go with [`bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/) by injecting as a dependency to angular application.

[`Sample Angularjs-Material App`](https://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV)

[`Sample Angualrjs-Bootstrap App`](https://plnkr.co/edit/TnYSU4?p=info)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I am specifically learning Angular JS for doing Single page application and wanna make it responsive!!

Comment: @Ganesh Yes , hope the above links does help, mark it as answer if it has really helped you